# Creating Specific Order Details from FactOrder table with DimProduct filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to distinct count the number of orders from the FactOrder table, and create a unique count of orders based on filtering details from a DimProduct table. Is there a way to create unique measures where you are filtering details from the DimProduct table, and filtering these details in a new measure within the FactOrder table?

This is all happening within a PowerBI workspace.

Comment: Can you just set the filters on the report, or are you trying to write a measure that always applies the same product filter? And if so do you want it to add to or replace the current filter on products?  Read generally about the CALCULATE function.  https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculate-in-dax/

Comment: I am looking to write a measure that always applies the same filters.